# Android smartPhone app support for Android Tablet

Tags: android, tablet

I am creating an application in Android. Originally i was making it only for smartphones but now i want that same app to uspport for Android Tablet. The problem is of scaling. It is not getting scaled to the size of Tablet screen. I have used LinearLayout with height and width as fill_parent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to read this piece of the manual: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

(please, do read it!)

But you could try adding the screen support in your androidmanifest.xml:

> The platform also provides a
>    manifest element,
>   whose attributes android:smallScreens,
>   android:normalScreens,
>   android:largeScreens, and
>   android:xlargeScreens let you specify
>   what generalized screen sizes your
>   application supports.

making it look like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

The [screen-support page](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) also states this: (emph mine)

> Maintain compatibility with existing
>   devices by **leaving your application's
>   android:minSdkVersion attribute as it
>   is.** You do not need to increment the
>   value of the attribute to support new
>   devices and multiple screens. Extend
>   compatibility for Android 1.6 (and
>   higher) devices by **adding a new
>   attribute — android:targetSdkVersion —**
>   to the uses-sdk element. Set the value
>   of the attribute to "4". [To support
>   xhdpi and xlarge screens, set the
>   value to "9".] This allows your
>   application to "inherit" the
>   platform's multiple screens support,
>   even though it is technically using an
>   earlier version of the API.

So the sollution as to update the minSdkVersion seems to be unwanted for the most general case. If you have '3' as a minSdkVersion for your situation, leave it at that, but add the targetSdkVersion for compatibility.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer. But I already did that. I had added the support-screens element but still it dint work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the min sdk version. If i set the min sdk version as 3 or less or not set it at all, the scaling problem occured. But if i set it to 4 or greater, it works perfectly fine. The application occupies the complete tablet screen height and width after setting the min sdk version equal or greater than 4.

Comment: I disagree that this is what you should do. I'll add 'why' to my anser ;)