# Make App compatible to tablet Android

Tags: android, tablet, google-play

I want to know what I have to change everything that my app is compatible to tablets.

At the moment in Play store it's shown that my application wouldn't be compatible to tablets.
I just did for some layouts a xlarge layout, what am I need have to do?
Thanks

Comment: See [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832664/app-not-compatible-with-tablet) as a possible duplicate; as well as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733070/why-is-app-not-compatible-with-tablets-after-update) and possibly more, by doing a thorough search first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why my App is not showing up on tablets in Google Play?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691775/why-my-app-is-not-showing-up-on-tablets-in-google-play)

Answer (score 5):

There may be a lot of issues . I am going to explain some of them.

Play Store detect devices on the basis of their requirement. I mean if you have added DiAL Permission or some permission which is not included in tablet . it will not download. use 
 uses-feature instead of permission and set the required attribute to false.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="false"/>
```

use the below code instead of above

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"  android:required="false"/>
```

and

for supprot screen

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />


<compatible-screens>
    <!--no small size screens -->


    <!--all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />

</compatible-screens>
```

and for xxhdpi

```
 <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
     <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
     <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="480" />`
```

see detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691775/why-my-app-is-not-showing-up-on-tablets-in-google-play)..

Comment: I have the following permissions in the manifest. Will my app show up for tablets? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/985de509ae8d68d72bf3

Comment: Check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955375/android-smartphone-app-support-for-android-tablet

Comment: The <support-screens> attribute should only be used if your `minSdkVersion < 13` as per the doc.

Answer (score 2):

The tablet may not support some of the features that your app requires.

Check Manifest for the following features -

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html.

The purpose of a `<uses-feature>` declaration is to inform any external entity of the set of hardware and software features on which your application depends.

To prevent the apps from being made available unintentionally, `Google Play` assumes that certain hardware-related permissions indicate that the underlying hardware features are required by default.

For instance, applications that use Bluetooth must request the `BLUETOOTH` permission in a `<uses-permission>` element — for legacy apps, Google Play assumes that the permission declaration means that the underlying `android.hardware.bluetooth` feature is required by the application and sets up filtering based on that feature.

For any of the permissions below, you can disable filtering based on the implied feature by explicitly declaring the implied feature explicitly, in a `<uses-feature>` element, with an `android:required="false"` attribute. For example, to disable any filtering based on the CAMERA permission, you would add this `<uses-feature>` declaration to the manifest file:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
```

As @ILMostro_7 pointed out in the comment, you should troubleshoot with `android:required="false"` and determine what missing feature in your tablet is causing the application to be not shown in Google Play.

If feature is not supported in tablet but is declared in manifest file without explicitly declaring as `android:required="false"`, then that tablet will be filtered out from Google Play.

Comment: So, in essence, search for `uses-feature` lines of code and check which one(s) are cause of problem; troubleshoot with `android:required="false"`

Comment: @ILMostro_7 - Exactly. If feature is not supported in tablet but is declared in manifest file without explicitly declaring as `android:required="false"`, then that tablet will be filtered out from Google Play.

Comment: I have the following permissions in the manifest. Will my app show up for tablets? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/985de509ae8d68d72bf3

Answer (score 0):

Add below code into your `android manifest.xml` file for make application tablet compatible.

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try to add this feature in AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
```

Comment: I have the following permissions in the manifest. Will my app show up for tablets? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/985de509ae8d68d72bf3